Dotnet garbage collector not collection objects when I change reference to null
I wanted to try how garbage collector works in .NET, but results are not clear for me.
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ~Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NICE");
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test instance = new Test()
        {
            Name = "Name"
        };
        instance = null;
        GC.Collect(3);
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine("FINISHED");
    }
}

in this code Nice is not printed. I think that it should print NICE, because I created object called instance and then I changed it's reference to null, which means that original reference now is in heap and there is not reference to it.
but then I wrote this code:
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ~Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("NICE");
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Test()
    {
        Test x = new Test();
        x = new Test();
        x = new Test();
        x = new Test();
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test();
        GC.Collect(3);
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Console.WriteLine("FINISHED");
    }
}

when I call Test() function, all 4 objects which was created in this function is finalized by garbage collector and NICE is printed 4 times.
can someone explain why first code does't print 'NICE'.
I think that I have wrong vision about garbage collector because of this behiaviour.

I am not exactly sure why that is; I would have assumed that the gc collects the objects. A modified version of your test has the same results, see http://dotnetfiddle.net/5teY0S. People always point out how C# garbage collection is non-deterministic, etc. But I would have assumed that an explicit collect() call causes all non-accessible objects to be reliably collected. Apparently not.

From the .NET Memory Performance Analysis FAQ: This is because when JIT generates code for you, it's free to lengthen the lifetime till end of the method. So in this case JIT simply extended the lifetime of o till the end of the Main method

The fact that you see nothing is actually an interesting result of two things.

The JIT has autonomy to extend an object's lifetime to the end of a scope.
This is why in your 2nd example, where the objects are declared in a different function, you see them get collected. Ref: This book was for earlier Framework versions, but looks like the behaviour hasn't changed.

Finalizers are not called at termination of program.
You may expect your finalizer - even if it's not called by the GC - would still be called when the app terminates. There's some discussion about it here (which also touches on point 1 above). But basically, no, it's not guaranteed. Please don't clean up resources in a finalizer, do it with a Dispose pattern instead.


